# How to Export AWS EC2 details to xlsx/csv using boto3 and python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, export-to-csv

When running this python code that we've created, it runs but the CSV file output only contains 1 detail but I have 100 instances that are assigned to our account. Can I ask on why this it only output 1 instances to csv when running it?

```
    import boto3
    import csv

    session = boto3.Session(profile_name="profile-name", 
    region_name="ap-southeast-1")

    ec2_re = session.resource(service_name="ec2")
    ec2_cli = session.client(service_name="ec2")

    # using resource object:

    print("Instances info with resource")
     for each_in in ec2_re.instances.all():
    print(each_in.id, each_in.security_groups, each_in.state['Name'])

    fo=open('ec2_inven_new.csv','w',newline='')
    data_obj=csv.writer(fo)
    data_obj.writerow([each_in.id,each_in.security_groups,each_in.state])

    fo.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are writing multiple times the same file. But could be a issue due to badly indentation in the code you shared.

You can try:

```py
import boto3
import csv
session = boto3.Session(profile_name="profile-name", 
region_name="ap-southeast-1")
ec2_re = session.resource(service_name="ec2")
ec2_cli = session.client(service_name="ec2")
# using resource object:
print("Instances info with resource")

fo = open('ec2_inven_new.csv','w',newline='')
data_obj = csv.writer(fo)
for each_in in ec2_re.instances.all():
    print(each_in.id, each_in.security_groups, each_in.state['Name'])
    data_obj.writerow([each_in.id,each_in.security_groups,each_in.state])

fo.close()
```

Comment: @ChristianJosefAquino you can accept the answer if that solves your issue

Comment: May I know how can I add the Tags like Key Name so I can get the instance name? I have added it in 

print(each_in.Key['Name'],each_in.id, each_in.security_groups, each_in.state['Name'])
data_obj.writerow([each_in.key, each_in.id,each_in.security_groups,each_in.state])

But now I can't extract it into CSV. Thanks to advise

Comment: Maybe is because in the print line you use `each_in.state['Name']` but in the line where is added to the csv, you use `each_in.state`?

Comment: I've tried adding and removing ['Name'] in each_in.key and each_in.state, but the CSV is still the same. I still can't extract the instance name via CSV.

Comment: Not sure about what you refer with instance name. You can get the public dns name with `each_in.public_dns_name` There are many other properties that you can get looking at the documentation https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Instance